1970s-1980s Paranormal Show
I'm trying to remember a show from when I was very young.
This show would have still been on TV in the late 80s and maybe early 90s. It was a drama with paranormal events and I think, but am not entirely sure, that it was on Disney or Nickelodeon since I didn't watch many channels at that age.
This was a live acted TV show (maybe a TV special or a TV movie?) which seemed to be about a small town with a big secret in current times.
One thing I do remember was that there were Native Americans in the cast and I think the town was near an Indian reservation.
The paranormal events were at one point implied to be Bigfoot or something similar and the Native Americans might have known more than they were letting on.
I think the show was mostly about people investigating strange happenings in a small town and weren't sure about which locals were involved. The biggest thing I remember about this show is that, at one point, one of the Native Americans takes them up onto a mountain or rocky crag that looks an awful lot like a skull to investigate some strange happenings and look for evidence.
They might have been investigating a murder or disappearance. Again, I was very young when I saw this but I think it might have had a sort of Twin Peaks (TV Series 1990–1991)  vibe. 
This has been something I've wanted to research for a while.
The big things I remember are the Native American members of the cast, paranormal behavior in the surrounding forests and mountains, and a large stone edifice or mountain that looks like a skull.
